# how to integrate mailjet?

Tags: android, mailjet

i am working on a android application that requires to send a welcome when a user signs up. I have done a little searching and found mailjet api. but i am not able to find how to integrate mailjet into android studio. can someone help me with this? or is there any other android api that i can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that hard, go to [MailJet](https://www.mailjet.com/email-api/)'s website and scroll a little, press the `JAVA` button on the demo window and vualla, you get a sample on how to send a message.